# Get latest SVN repository commit in PHP

Tags: php, batch-file, svn

The way I'm doing this at the moment is having a batch file and running the batch file, the batch file then writes to a file with the latest repository commit version. Once the version is inside the text file, I'll read the text file and display the version on my web page.

**current batch file:**

```
@echo off

:: Loop through TortoiseSVN and get the latest version number of the working copy
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('svn info -rHEAD svn://192.168.1.16^|find "Revision"') do set version=%%i
:: Delete current versionNumber text file
del generateFunctions\textFiles\versionNumber.txt
:: Print out version number into versionNumber text file
@echo 1.1.%version% >> generateFunctions\textFiles\versionNumber.txt

exit
```

**PHP file:**

```
//  Create variable for the file contents to be stored 
$getVersionNumber = file_get_contents('../generateFunctions/textFiles/versionNumber.txt');

// Check to see if there is any value inside the getVersionNumber variable 
if (0 == strlen($getVersionNumber)) 
{ 
    // If there is not a value inside the variable then print out "Not found"
    echo "<b>Version:</b> Not found";
} 
else 
{
    // If there is a value inside the variable then print out the version number
    echo $getVersionNumber;
}
```

**What  I'm looking for:**

I'm looking for a way of doing this with just PHP so that I can just call the PHP file on page ready and get the latest version that way.

Does anyone have any idea if this is possible?

Comment: I dont't know how your repo is setup, but maby mod-dav-svn can help you. With that you can make your repository accessible by an URL, so you can do a CURL request at your PHP script for entering the repo.

Comment: You can get the svn info by executing command through PHP.

Comment: @sanderbee the repo is on a local machine in the office, so you're saying there needs to be a external URL for this? and doesn't CURL requests run abit slowly?

Comment: That is a way i know that works. Otherwise you have to perform shell commands like shell_exec() or something like that to excecute the wanted SVN commands.